# perl -w VS use warnings

Tags: perl

We had some discussion on perl coding standards, one is about using

```
perl -w
```

or

```
use warnings
```

Some prefer the later one because of below reasons:

1. use warnings can be applied selectively
2. categories of warnings can be enabled and disabled (-w is either completely on or off)

How do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Perl documentation itself talks about this issue in [What's wrong with -w and $^W](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html#What%27s-wrong-with-%2a-w%2a-and-%24%5EW).

The `warnings` pragma is a newer feature that was introduced as a replacement for `-w`. Its main advantage is it allows more control since, as you mentioned, it can be applied selectively. I.e. it applies within the scope of the enclosing block where it is used (and it can be disabled within a sub-block where you want warnings to be suppressed for something that you knowingly will produce a warning).